# How I do adjust the offset, space between labels in this instance, in reportlab/report lab for python/tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, reportlab

I am using reportlab.shapes to create a sticker label sheet.  However, I need there to be no spacing between labels when they print as shown in screenshot, so they will fit the sheet.  I have tried, and am still trying using labelOffset from reportlab, but am having no luck.  Am I heading down the right path, and if so, what would I need to adjust?  If not, any and all direction, thoughts, help, input is greatly appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import font
from reportlab.graphics import shapes
from reportlab.graphics.charts.textlabels import LabelOffset
import os
import labels


root = Tk()
root.geometry("900x500")
     
data_frame = LabelFrame(root, background ='#fadc91')
data_frame.pack()
    
lname_label = Label(data_frame, text = "Name, Last:", font = 'Helvetica 11 bold', background ='#fadc91')
lname_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
def my_lname(*args):
    str1.set(str1.get().upper())
str1=StringVar()
lname = Entry(data_frame, textvariable=str1, width=40)
lname.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
str1.trace('w', my_lname)
    
fname_label = Label(data_frame, text = "First:", font = 'Helvetica 11 bold', background ='#fadc91')
fname_label.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
def my_fname(*args):
    str2.set(str2.get().upper())
str2=StringVar()
fname = Entry(data_frame, textvariable=str2, width=40)
fname.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)
str2.trace('w', my_fname)

mname_label = Label(data_frame, text = "Middle Initial:", font = 'Helvetica 11 bold', background ='#fadc91')
mname_label.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)
def my_mname(*args):
    str3.set(str3.get().upper())
str3=StringVar()
mname = Entry(data_frame, textvariable=str3, width=5)
mname.grid(row=0, column=5, padx=10, pady=10)
str3.trace('w', my_mname)

fnum_label = Label(data_frame, text = "FIN:", font = 'Helvetica 11 bold', background ='#fadc91')
fnum_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
fnum = Entry(data_frame, width=30)
fnum.grid(row=1, column=1)

adate_label = Label(data_frame, text = "Admitted:", font = 'Helvetica 11 bold', background ='#fadc91')
adate_label.grid(row=1, column=2)
adate = Entry(data_frame, width=30)
adate.grid(row=1, column=3)

bday_label = Label(data_frame, text = "DOB:", font = 'Helvetica 11 bold', background ='#fadc91')
bday_label.grid(row=3, column=0)
bday = Entry(data_frame, width=30)
bday.grid(row=3, column=1)


sex = IntVar()
 
gen_label = Label(data_frame, text = "Gender:", font = 'Helvetica 11 bold', background ='#fadc91')
gen_label.grid(row=3, column=2)

mbutton = Radiobutton(data_frame, text="Male", variable=sex, value=1, font = 'Helvetica 11 bold', background ='#fadc91')
mbutton.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky=W)

fbutton = Radiobutton(data_frame, text="Female", variable=sex, value=2, font = 'Helvetica 11 bold', background ='#fadc91')
fbutton.grid(row=4, column=3, sticky=W)

ubutton = Radiobutton(data_frame, text="Unknown", variable=sex, value=3, font = 'Helvetica 11 bold', background ='#fadc91')
ubutton.grid(row=3, column=3)

my_label5 = Label(root, text = "    ", font = 'Helvetica 14 bold', background ='#fadc91')
my_label5.pack()

edit_frame = LabelFrame(root, font = 'Helvetica 12 bold', background ='#fadc91')
edit_frame.pack()

 
global specs
specs = labels.Specification(215.9, 279.4, 4, 15, 44.5, 17.4625, corner_radius=2)

    
def draw_label(label, width, height, lines):
    label.add(shapes.String(2, 38, lines[0], fontName="Helvetica", fontSize=10))
    label.add(shapes.String(2, 28, lines[1], fontName="Helvetica", fontSize=10))
    label.add(shapes.String(2, 18, lines[2], fontName="Helvetica", fontSize=10))
    label.add(shapes.String(2, 8, lines[3], fontName="Helvetica", fontSize=10))


def create_label():
    global sheet
    if sex.get() == 1:
        gender = "M"
    elif sex.get() == 2:
        gender = "F"
    else:
        gender = "U"

    name_line = (lname.get() + ", " + fname.get() + " " + mname.get())
    fin = fnum.get()
    admit_date = ("ADM: " + adate.get())
    dbsxline = ("DOB: " + bday.get() + "          " + gender)
               

    sheet = labels.Sheet(specs, draw_label, border=True)


    sheet.add_label([fin, name_line, dbsxline, admit_date], count = 60)


def make_label():
    sheet.save('downtime_labels.pdf')
    print("{0:d} label(s) output on {1:d} page(s).".format(sheet.label_count, sheet.page_count))
    
    os.startfile("downtime_labels.pdf", "print")
    
    
ml_button = Button(edit_frame, text="Print Labels", font='Helvetica 12 bold', background='light gray', command = lambda: [create_label(), make_label()])
ml_button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

[sample printout to pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmW7V.png)

Comment: Did you try to set the label width to `page_width / columns` and label height to `page_height / rows`? For your case, label width is around `215.9 / 4` and label height is around `279.4 / 15`.

Comment: @acw1668 I did not.  Where would I drop that in at?

Comment: In `specs = labels.Specification(...)`.

Comment: Ahh gotcha!  That will get me where I am going.  Thank you so much!!  Can you put the above as an answer, so I can marked it solved for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove those space between labels, you should calculate the size of the label based on the page size and number of rows and columns.

For your case:

- page width = 215.9
- page height = 279.4
- number of columns = 4
- number of rows = 15

So the label width is `215.9 / 4` which is around `53.97` and the label height is `279.4 / 15` which is around `18.62`:

```py
specs = labels.Specification(215.9, 279.4, 4, 15, 53.97, 18.62, corner_radius=2)
```

Comment: That did it!!  Thank you so much!!